# Foreach PHP facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have to the following code which is returned from the Facebook API:

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Mobile Uploads [id] => 680467525306684 [created_time] => 2013-12-09T10:17:39+0000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Timeline Photos [id] => 588255297861241 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T20:12:14+0000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Mercedes CLK55 AMG - Wide Conversion [id] => 732173653469404 [created_time] => 2014-03-20T20:45:17+0000 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => NISSAN 350Z Colour Change.. [id] => 677937242226379 [created_time] => 2013-12-04T13:38:26+0000 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => TOYOTA SURF [id] => 675809505772486 [created_time] => 2013-11-29T16:36:08+0000 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => HONDA CIVIC TYPE R EP3 [id] => 667129319973838 [created_time] => 2013-11-13T16:12:05+0000 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Mercedes SL65 Conversion [id] => 661587023861401 [created_time] => 2013-11-02T16:33:48+0000 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 2003 Mercedes SL - SL65 Conversion [id] => 661525630534207 [created_time] => 2013-11-02T13:58:05+0000 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [name] => HONDA FIREBLADE CBR1000 [id] => 657704500916320 [created_time] => 2013-10-26T16:15:56+0000 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [name] => WIDE ARCHED MK5 GOLF [id] => 621816751171762 [created_time] => 2013-08-17T13:04:41+0000 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [name] => YAMAHA QUAD BIKE [id] => 588281337858637 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T21:42:58+0000 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Cover Photos [id] => 588150447871726 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T15:37:58+0000 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [name] => AUDI A6 3.0TDI QUATTRO [id] => 588117341208370 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T14:39:59+0000 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [name] => BMW 535D TWIN TURBO [id] => 588113591208745 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T14:30:07+0000 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [name] => AUDI A4 SE [id] => 588110747875696 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T14:22:35+0000 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Profile Pictures [id] => 588096834543754 [created_time] => 2013-06-06T13:47:27+0000 ) ) [paging] => stdClass Object ( [cursors] => stdClass Object ( [after] => NTg4MDk2ODM0NTQzNzU0 [before] => NjgwNDY3NTI1MzA2Njg0 ) ) ) )
```

These are photo albums pulled in from a Facebook page. I want to loop through them and get the "name", "ID", etc but it appears a normal foreach function returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphObject as array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/facebook/index.php on line 29
```

Here's the full logic:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/588091587877612/albums?fields=name'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$albums = $response->getGraphObject();

print_r ($albums);

foreach($albums['data'] as $album) {
    echo $album['name'];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why that error is being returned?

Thanks in advance,
Connor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try :

```
$albums = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0), it looks like you're not handling the data correctly.

Untested, but here's a suggestion:

```
$albums = $response->getGraphObject();
$albums_data = $albums->getProperty('data');
foreach ($albums_data as $album) {
    echo $album->name;
}
```